# Eliminating last element in a string of 3 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help in making this program take a DNA sequence and break it up into **3s**(**ATGCGTGGC**=>**ATG,CGT,CCG**) to create **codons**. Then from there it will compare that codon to the '**genecode**' dictionary in my code. It seems to work just fine until it gets to the end of the last line where a single '**G**' is causing the program to fail because it doesn't match a 3 character long string in the **'genecode'** dictionary. Basically the final solution will be to eliminate all letters (nucleotides) at the end of the sequence that is less than 3.

Code is below:

```
genecode = {
  'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M',
  'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
  'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
  'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
  'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
  'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
  'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
  'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
  'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
  'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
  'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'Glu',
  'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
  'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
  'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
  'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_',
  'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W'}      

Gene1=open("HBB Norm.csv", "r")        
Gene2=open("HBB Pos (Sickle Cell).csv", "r")

##HBB Norm and HBB Pos (Sickle Cell) are just the names of the csv files I want to import data from 

Gene_1=Gene1.read()
Gene_11=''.join(Gene_1.splitlines())
Gene_2=Gene2.read() 
Gene_22=''.join(Gene_2.splitlines())

for codon in range(0,len(Gene_11),3):  
  gene_11=Gene_11[codon:codon+3]
  print(genecode[gene_11])
```

The specific error that is showing up is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 111, in <module>
    print(genecode[gene_11])
    KeyError: 'G'
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your string isn't a multiple of 3. Says your string is ATAAC you'll first check ATA and getI, but then AC won't be in your list. To solve this, you can change how far you itterare:

```
for codon in range(0, len(Gene_11) - len(Gene_11)%3, 3):
```

Comment: Hey this is basically what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!  I think ideally, i'd like the program to eliminate the last iteration of letters if the length is less than 3 letters long.  But for my purposes I think this answer is totally fine because not all letters (nucleotides) need to be transcribed into a codon. Thanks so much!

Comment: @nlsn243 glad to help! Could you accept the answer to close yhe question?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `get` to get the value from the dictionary instead of indexing, and provide a default value I don't know what a nucleotide is but I presume you mean an empty string here

```
print(genecode.get(gene_11, ""))
```

Specifically, You're getting the error because there is no value in your dictionary for the key `'G'`. So you could always check if the key is in the dictionary before trying to print it

```
print(genecode[gene_11] if gene_11 in genecode else "")
```